# IBM Datapower - AWS VPC API connectivity issues

Tags: amazon-web-services, ibm-datapower

We have added AWS VPC cloud as an extension to on-premise infrastructure just recently. I am working on an implementation where we have lambda based VPC API exposed by AWS and we are trying to consume these from IBM datapower. Some more details.

- AWS API has two headers - **x-api-key & host**
- AWS has json API format
- Some third party will call datapower which in turn will connect to AWS API
- Datapower is using mpgw object

But we are not able to do so and getting errors. Any help will be highly appreciated.

`mpgw (XXX): Error in stream. Descriptor number unavailable. Additional information: Write error (8)`

```
mpgw (XXX): Network Error on back side server https://xxxx.execute-api.ap-xxx-1.amazonaws.com/xx/yy
```

We tried to finetune some network setting but no luch but adding to surprise is that we are able to connect to AWS API from IBM API connect fine.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve the issue?